# MySQL join tables without cartesian product

Tags: mysql, join, cartesian-product

I have dataset like this

| group_id | a_id | b_id | c_id | d_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **1** | null | null | null |
| 1 | null | **2** | null | null |
| 1 | null | null | **3** | null |
| 1 | null | null | null | **4** |
| 1 | null | null | null | **5** |
| 2 | **11** | null | null | null |
| 2 | null | **12** | null | null |
| 2 | null | null | **13** | null |

Each record contain only 1 `*_id` for each `group_id`. I need to aggregate datasets for each `group_id`.

Result:

| group_id | a_id | b_id | c_id | d_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **1** | **2** | **3** | **4** |
| 1 | null | null | null | **5** |
| 2 | **11** | **12** | **13** | null |

Some `*_id` could be null (row 3 for `group_id`).
And it's important to avoid cartesian product (in my example row 2 contains only `d_id` = 5 because first 4 rows aggregated in one, and there no more non-aggregated `a_id`, `b_id` and `c_id` with `group_id`=1).

Is it possible to do this with MySQL joins?

Comment: Why d_id=4 is included into combined group and d_id=5 is not, why not backward?

Comment: Does something (CHECK constraint?) provides strictly "three NULL and one value per row" in source data?

Comment: @Akina d_id=5 included into combined group too. There 2 combined groups for group_id=1 (rows 1 and 2).

Comment: @Akina i don't need check constraints because null id is normal situation.

Comment: Is the dataset being formatted this way for the sake of a front-end tool that will then iterate through the data? Would it be possible to have multiple values grouped and comma-separated, like: `4,5`? 

Comment: @matigo yes, this dataset prepared for usage on front-end. Unfortunately i need to show rows like in my example (combine *_id's if it's possible and show empty cells when some *_id's is null).

Comment: *d_id=5 included into combined group too.* Well, why d_id=4 is included into 1st combined group and d_id=5 into 2nd, why not backward?

Comment: *i don't need check constraints because null id is normal situation.* i.e. the situation when, for example, a_id and c_id are set in the same row of the source data and b_id and d_id are NULL, is a norma?

Comment: @akina 1 - because result dataset formed as combining unique a_id, b_id, c_id and d_id. We need to get lists of all *_id's and show them in table in UI as 4 independent columns. I know in terms of relational database it not entirely correct, but i need this structure of data in my result. 2 - yes, it's normal. Actually situation that you desrcibed (a_id and c_id is both not null) doesn't meet in source data table. Only one of a/b/c/d_id is not null. Rest are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte_a AS ( SELECT group_id, a_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) rn
           FROM test
           WHERE a_id IS NOT NULL ),
cte_b AS ( SELECT group_id, b_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) rn
           FROM test
           WHERE b_id IS NOT NULL ),
cte_c AS ( SELECT group_id, c_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) rn
           FROM test
           WHERE c_id IS NOT NULL ),
cte_d AS ( SELECT group_id, d_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) rn
           FROM test
           WHERE d_id IS NOT NULL ),
cte_n AS ( SELECT group_id, rn FROM cte_a
           UNION
           SELECT group_id, rn FROM cte_b
           UNION
           SELECT group_id, rn FROM cte_c
           UNION
           SELECT group_id, rn FROM cte_d )
SELECT group_id,
       cte_a.a_id,
       cte_b.b_id,
       cte_c.c_id,
       cte_d.d_id
FROM cte_n
LEFT JOIN cte_a USING (group_id, rn)
LEFT JOIN cte_b USING (group_id, rn)
LEFT JOIN cte_c USING (group_id, rn)
LEFT JOIN cte_d USING (group_id, rn)
ORDER BY group_id, rn;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87281205ad06780b71b0e90355751e88

PS. If more than one value from `*_id` is not NULL in a row then it is possible that these values will occur in different output rows.